# Парсинг сайтов из списка ссылок при помощи BeautifulSoup (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

У меня есть текстовый документ с ссылками на записи на стене сообщества в вк в ввиде https://vk.com/wall-..._...., и мне нужно вытащить из этих записей ссылки на видео(находящиеся в посте) вида https://vk.com/video-....._....

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

writefile = open('wrtfile.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
readfile = open('vk_walls.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
vk_wall_link = "https://vk.com/video"


for line in readfile:
    f = line.strip()
    with open(f) as site:
        src = site.readlines()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

        f_links = soup.find("div", class_="wall_text").findAll("a")
        print(f_links)
        print("#" * 20)

        for link in f_links:
            item_url = link.get("href")

            if vk_wall_link in item_url:
                writefile.write(item_url)
writefile.close()
```

Для начала я попробовал с одной ссылкой и всё получилось, но указав файл стало выдавать ошибку. Как мне сделать чтобы строчка из файла ставилась на место f (в 10 строчке кода)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm Projects\Download from list of links\files\my_file.py", line 10, in <module>
    with open(f) as site:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://vk.com/...._....'
```

Comment: Полученная ссылка не является файлом, а вы пытаетесь как файл и открыть.

Comment: попробуйте разделить код на составляющие: - прочитать все ссылки из vk_walls.txt; - в цикле делать запрос к каждой из них; - найденные на странице ссылки добавлять в список; - после цикла все найденные ссылки сохранить в файл wrtfile.txt